# Change Image Without Reloading in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, data-binding, angular-services

How can i change the image in angular without reloading the page? I have several users and every change in users also has change in image. right now, i need to reload the page to actually see the image change. How not to make it reload anymore?

> ts

```
 private image1 = `assets/images/image${localStorage.getItem('user_id')}.jpg`;
```

> html

```
<img [src]="image1">
```

> select user.ts

```
onSelectUser(form: NgForm) {
    const user = form.value.org;
    this.userService.selectedUser(user)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log(data);
            localStorage.setItem('user_id', data.user.id);

          },
          error => {
             console.log(error);
          });
  }
```

Comment: Where do you change the value of `image1`?

Comment: look into dataUrls

Comment: @Z.Bagley. Just when the user_id changes in the local storage. I've also added the some codes above.

Comment: @theGleep. I'm sorry?

Comment: If you set the image source to a dataUrl, it will change the image.  You can generate the dataUrl as part of an Ajax call, or using the media APIs if you're wanting to show a picture that was selected on the local computer.

Comment: @theGleep. Do you have any sample codes?

Comment: None of my own, but here's an article that might help: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2966-rendering-image-previews-using-object-urls-vs-base64-data-uris-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to trigger image loading is to reassign `src` and trigger change detection, for example with `setTimeout`:

```
this.userService.selectedUser(user)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        localStorage.setItem('user_id', data.user.id);
        this.image1 = '';
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.image1 = '...jpg';
        });

      },
      ...
```

Of course, this depends on caching. If image URL stays the same and server caching policy allowed it to be cached (usually this is true for images), it will still loaded from cache. In this case browser cache should be busted with URL change, similarly to how jQuery does for AJAX requests.

Considering that a server is ok with requests that add query string to the URL (usually this isn't a problem), it's simply:

```
this.userService.selectedUser(user)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        localStorage.setItem('user_id', data.user.id);
        this.image1 = '...jpg?_=' + Date.now();
      },
      ...
```

Comment: I'll try this. Thanks for this